# Sending a POST request to a URL from C#

Tags: c#, api, post, httpwebrequest

I have a Node server hosted with Azure, where I can send a POST request to the API for it to perform some function. The API itself works, I have tested it with [Post Man](https://www.getpostman.com/).

A call to the API would look something like this..

`http://website.com/api/Foo?name=bar&second=example`

This doesn't necessarily need to return anything, as the call is silent and does something in the background. (note: perhaps it *must* return something and this is a hole in my understanding of the concept?)

---

Using C#, how can I make a web request to this URL?

I am already constructing the URL based on parameters passed to my method (so name and type as above could be whatever was passed to the method)

It's the POSTing to this URL that I cannot get working correctly.

This is the code I have tried..

```
        void MakeCall(string name, string second)
        {
           string url = "http://website.com/api/Foo?name="+name+"&second="+second;
           HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
           request.Method = "POST";
           request.ContentType = "application/json";
           request.ContentLength = url.Length;
           HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a request stream and write to it, this link here has several ways to do this either with `HttpWebRequest`, `HttpClient` or using 3rd party libraries:

[Posting data using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Dan. All working now, using the Third method mentioned in the answer you linked.